# CSS: Is it possible to use only a set part of an image as a background filler?

Tags: css, background-image

I have background image for a site header with fixed width. Now I am trying to convert it to a stretching layout.

Is it possible (in CSS2) to take 1px wide portion from the middle of that header image and make a filler out of it? Otherwise I would need to manually cut 1px wide portion of an image, save it as a separated image, and use it with `repeat-x`.

Comment: just curious. why can't you cut the pixel? Will you send a complete image to the client just to use 1px?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but all I am trying to do is to avoid extra work :)

Comment: It *is* possible, but you wouldn't want to do it :p You can horizontally fill the area with 1px wide divs with the background image set to the said image with the right background position. * ducks *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using css only you cannot do this. So your proposed solution is the one that I would use.

Answer (score 2):

No. CSS 2 has no such ability.

Answer (score 1):

Not in CSS2, but in CSS3 you could with the [border-image](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images) property.

Browser support isn't there yet though. Only the latest releases have it and not IE at all yet.